# Can anyone explain why I am getting this error in Javascript? [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

Here is my code:

```
function isEven(num) {;
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
  return true;}
  else {
  return false;}
  }

function convertToIntegers(lst) {
  lst.split(' ');
  var len = lst.length;
  var count = 0;
  while (count < len) {
      lst[count] = parseInt(lst[count]);
      count++}
      }




function iqTest(numbers){

  var int_list = convertToIntegers(numbers);
  var e_list = [];
  var o_list = [];
  var count = 0;
  var len_int = int_list.length;
  while (count < len_int) {
      if (isEven(int_list[count]) === true) {
      e_list.push(count);}
      else if (isEven(count) === false) {
      o_list.push(count);}
      count++}
  if (e_list.length < 2 && e_list.length > 0 && o_list.length > 2) {
      return e_list[0];}
  else if (o_list.length < 2 && o_list.length > 0 && e_list.length > 2) {
      return o_list[0];}
      }
```

Everytime I run it I get this error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at iqTest". Can anyone explain to me how I can fix this error. I don't understand why any object would be undefined in my code. Every var declaration I make is complete.  I thought undefined only came up if I wrote something like  'var a' without defining it.

Comment: `lst.split(' ');` you are not saving the result anywhere, `.split()` does not mutate the original variable.

Comment: Can you update with your attempts to troubleshoot the problem, if any?

Comment: @RobG, I know that, actually that was part of my comment, but someone made it an answer so I removed it from my comment. The split() comment was just letting them know their logic was wrong in that part as well

Comment: @PatrickEvans—cool. It would be a good idea for the OP to post code that didn't have syntax and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

this one is very easy!
in these situations you want to trace the value back.

1. you use `.length` in `iqTest()` in the line `var len_int = int_list.length;`
2. the last assignment to `int_list` is at line `var int_list = convertToIntegers(numbers);`
3. glimps at `convertToIntegers(numbers)` shows no `return` statement.

therefore conclusion:
`convert2Integers()` returns nothing into `int_list`
then you use `int_list.length;` of `undefined`

it seems you wish to return `lst` from `convert2Integers()`

```
function convertToIntegers(lst) {
  lst = lst.split(' '); // NOTICE CHANGE, + create a different list!
  var len = lst.length;
  var count = 0;
  while (count < len) {
    lst[count] = parseInt(lst[count]);
    count++
  }
  return lst; //THIS LINE was Missing!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomer W and Patrick Evans are right. change your helper function

```
function convertToIntegers(lst) {
  lst = lst.split(' ');
  var len = lst.length;
  var count = 0;
  while (count < len) {
    lst[count] = parseInt(lst[count]);
    count++;
  }
  return lst;
}
```

this way you are storing th result of the split and then returning the array when done.

that being said this function isn't needed. Check out the built in array function [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Patrick Evans comment you need to save the result of the split then use that for your while loop.  Just as a side note you know the number of iterations of the loop so you can use a for loop.

```
function convertToIntegers(lst) {
//lst.split(' ');
var lst_array = lst.split(' ');
var len = lst_array .length;
var count = 0;
while (count < len) {
  lst_array[count] = parseInt(lst_array[count]);
  count++}
  }
//
//for loop code
//
//for(i=0;i<lst_array.length;i++){
//  lst_arry[i] = parseInt(lst_array[i]);
//}
```